# How to convert the dictionary values to lower case in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, lowercase

I have a list of dictionaries which is,

```
list_dict = [{'name':'Rita' , 'customer_id': 'A12B1', 'city': 'Chennai'}, 
             {'name':'Sita' , 'customer_id': 'A61B8', 'city': 'Salem'}]
```

I need to get the result as,

```
list_dict = [{'name':'rita' , 'customer_id': 'a12b1', 'city': 'chennai'}, 
             {'name':'sita' , 'customer_id': 'a61b8', 'city': 'salem'}]
```

I have tried with,

```
new_list = []
for index in range(len(list_dict)):
    new_dict = {}
    for key,val in list_dict[index].items():
        new_dict[key] = str(val).lower()
new_list.append(new_dict)
```

How can I achieve the same result using list comprehension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
[{ key: str(value).lower() for key, value in e.items() } for e in list_dict ]
```

Basically, you have to use a list comprehension that contains a dict comprehension.

Comment: casting to `str` seems unnecessary, at least in the sample data.

Comment: @AdamSmith, I agree with you, but the author of the question made that edit.

Comment: @Adam Smith, If suppose the values are integers, then this does not work => [{ key: value.lower() for key, value in e.items() } for e in list_dict ]

Comment: @MahamuthaM, I think you should mention that in your question to avoid this confusion. Otherwise, the code I originally provided is enough.

Comment: @MahamuthaM yes, but in that case your sample data isn't very representative :) That's fine, it's just confusing for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_dict = [ { k:v.lower() for k,v in d.items() } for d in list_dict ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to use a list comprehension that contains a dict comprehension.

[ { k:v.lower() for k,v in s.items() } for s in list_dict ]